# Convergence of poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $X\sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ observations following this distribution.
I want to derive the analytical solution of the following series:
$$\ell(\lambda):=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log P(X=x_i).$$

EDIT: After a few trials, I found a good numerical approximation of the solution:
$$\ell(\lambda)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(17.08\cdot \lambda).$$
See the graph below, where the dots represent an approximation of the solution by simulating poisson distributions, while the blue line represents the approximated numerical solution.

```
x=1:1000
y=sapply(x,function(x) mean(log(dpois(rpois(100000,x),x))))
plot(x,y)
lines(x,-log(sqrt(x*17.08)),col="blue")
```

[image: Numerical solution]

Comment: That's right on the mark: the constant is $2\pi e \approx 17.07947.$ See the formula for entropy at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution.  As a check, follow up with `curve(-(log(2*pi*exp(1)*x)/2 - 1/(12*x) - 1/(24*x^2) - 19/(360*x^3)), add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2, n=501)` as suggested by the formula at that page. BTW, for faster iteration you don't need such a tightly spaced set of $\lambda.$  Use, say, `x=exp(seq(0, 20, by=1/2))` and include `log="x"` as an argument to `plot`.

Comment: Thanks whuber, I didn't know that what I wanted to calculate was actually the entropy! If you had added an answer instead of commenting my question, I could have selected it as the right answer.

Comment: Your use of the word "serie", with no final "s" makes me wonder if you're more accustomed to French than to English. Or was that just a typo? $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $n$ samples of a random variables $Y$  (or equivalently, $n$ iid random variables) and you compute the sample mean as

$$ m_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$$

then, as $n$ grows, (under certain conditions) $m_n$ will converge (in some sense) to the expected value of $Y$, that is $m_n \to E[Y]$. See the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), which clarifies those "certain conditions" and in what sense the "convergence" occurs.

In our case, $Y=\log(p(X))$ hence

$$\begin{align}
 m_n \to E[\log(p(X)]&=\sum_x p_X(x) \log(p_X(x)) \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^\infty  e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} (-\lambda + x \log(\lambda) - \log(x!)) \\
&= -\lambda (1 - \log(\lambda)) - e^{-\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}\log(x!)
\end{align}$$

This cannot be put in simpler form, but for large $\lambda$ it can be shown that it tends to $ -\frac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi e \lambda)$

Except for the sign, as noted in a comment, this is the entropy of a Poisson distribution, see eg [here](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/1959440/Metis199989.pdf) or the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

BTW, if you look for higher order correction terms, bear in mind that most results in the bibliography imply a base two logarithm (as usual in information theory).